# What is meant by "have a state"?

Tags: flutter

From `StatefulWidget` API:

> A widget that has mutable **state**.

From `State` API:

> The logic and internal **state** for a StatefulWidget.

My interpretation of state is basically *instance fields* of an object or *properties* of an object.
Based on the same APIs, `StatefulWidget` only has these 3 properties: `hashcode`, `key`, `runtimeType`.

Clearly, `StatefulWidget` does not have a 'has-a' relationship with `State` as mentioned by the API. Being very new to Flutter, the only way I know that `StatefulWidget` accesses `State` is via the `createState()` method, this seems to indicate a dependency relationship rather than 'has-a'.

Hence, my question: What is meant to "have a state" since `StatefulWidget` does not have a 'has-a' relationship with `State`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it simple, `State` stands for the data that can be changed/ manipulated. For example it can be `Colors`, `Size` or `Text` value of a Widget. Look at this simple widget:

```dart
class SampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleWidgetState createState() => _SampleWidgetState();
}

class _SampleWidgetState extends State<SampleWidget> {
  String label = 'Sample Button';
  Color? labelColor = Colors.black;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      height: 45,
      child: TextButton(
        child: Text(label),
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            primary: labelColor,
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            textStyle: UITextStyle.buttonStyle()),
        onPressed: () => setState(() {
          labelColor = Colors.red;
          label = 'Button Pressed';
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here we have 2 states: The content of the button's label and the color of the label. By pressing the button, we change the content and color to different value, thus manipulating the `State` of this `StatefulWidget`.

There are 2 general types of `State` according to [the documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/ephemeral-vs-app). This is a good start to understand what the `State` means within the Flutter framework.

Comment: Am I correct to say the API in my question was referring to app state? 
Also, are `label` and `labelColor` ephemeral states and is `_SampleWidgetState` an app state?

Comment: Yes `label` and `labelColor` are `ephemeral state`. The `app state` are those that usually prolonged during the running of an app, which can be the app's theme, the user's login state, etc. For your question, I think it's more of an `ephemeral state` since `app state` needs to be passed from the top down the widget trees, which involved several widgets that share the states with each others. Only state that is contained within the context of one widget is `ephemeral state`